# Where is the document root of the server when yarn start is started with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the location where the resource is located on the local PC when `yarn start` is started with create-react-app.

Where is the development server's document root in my PC?

Comment: `public/index.html`. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @azium No, I want to know about the built js file referenced by the development server (localhost: 3000).

When access "http: // localhost: 3000", it is loaded like "/static/js/bundle.js" , "/static/js/0.chunk.js", "/static/js/main.chunk.js" , "/main.{random}.hot-update.js".

Comment: It's somewhere in `node_modules`. Why do you want to know this btw?

Comment: I use React as part of the SaaS web system.
I don't provide a development environment for this system, so I need to upload a JS file.
The development efficiency is poor if you do a release build every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into public/index.html.
in that you will see below element.

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

then look for index.js file in your src folder.
you will see below line.

```
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

that means it is generating App component and attaching the dynamically generated html to div id "root"

Comment: I want to know the location of JS files such as intermediate files that are read when accessing "https://localhost:3000/".
Thank you.

Comment: yarn start will look package.json in your project folder. In package.json there is a start script which is  "start": "react-scripts start", now look into node_modules folder and find folder for react-scripts/ from there it will run /node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js which in turn will call /node_modules/react-scripts/start.js, in that you will find a line  devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {} you can dig further for whatever information you want to dig. this  spinups webpack server for you will find configuration in node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js